# monacaでgooglemapsapiを利用したマップが表示されません

Tags: monaca, google-maps

```
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
```

上記を記載すると、以下を利用したmapの表示ができません。

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }
</script>
```

components/loader.jsを読み込まないと、map表示ができるのですが。。。
非常に初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、該当の質問で同じ状況の質問がなかったので、質問いたしました。monaca x googlemapsapi、難しいです。

Answer (score 1):

おそらく`initialize()`を呼んだ時点で`div#map_canvas`がまだ読み込まれていないのではないかと疑っていますが、いかんせん情報が少なすぎます。`loader.js`で読み込んでいるプラグインの内容（jQueryとか、OnsenUIとか）、および`initialize()`の呼び出し部分も含めたコードの全体を提示していただけると解決が早いと思います。